# Handling specific Java version for desktop application

Tags: java, maven, javafx-8

What is the best way to handle situation, when a Java desktop application (executable JAR) requires specific (or newer) version/update of Java, to not get some NoClassDef exceptions?

Details: I have JavaFX 8 desktop application, build with Maven and com.zenjava.javafx-maven-plugin to executable JAR. I'm using new features of JDK 8u40. I would like to nicely handle situation, when someone is trying to run it with older Java version.

First, most low-end approach is to check

```
System.getProperty("java.version");
```

at the start of main function, parse it with a couple of "ifs" to extract is it major >= 8 and update >= 40, if not show some popup instead of app. But it seems to me like mediocre solution.

I wonder are there better ways? I'd love to know more about direct code solutions, external libs, additional jar launchers or Maven options for this purpose.

Edit: additional info - I would like to avoid platform-specific solutions

Comment: You could use something like JWrapper to bundle the correct JRE along with your application. Downside of that is your download becomes larger, and you need to create platform-specific applications.

Answer (score 1):

The solution which mostly works: just create a native bunde **with included JRE**. This is the default when calling `mvn jfx:native`, so you shouldn't worry about the class being there, because you bundled that specific version.

That is the [main reason why some](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-launcher/issues/33#issuecomment-157153757) are using that option. Just imagine the situation you are require Java 8 but the user just uses Java 7 and so on, it makes the bundle bigger, indeed, but it preserves you from such problems.

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin), there are [example-projects](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it) ;) but no cookies yet.